# Can't add each items quantity to list in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Trying to update each items quantity and add it to a list to get total price but when adding one item's quantity other items quantity will not be added

```
IconButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          if (widget.quantity[index] > 1) {
                            setState(() {
                              widget.quantity[index]--;
                              list.insert(index,widget.quantity[index]);
                            });
                          }
                        },
                        icon: const Icon(
                          Icons.remove,
                          color: Color.fromRGBO(246, 121, 82, 1),
                        )),
```

Expected to see each items quantity but only see one

Comment: Hello, Can you please share a more detailed code so I can provide the proper solution to you. Thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.